# Returning the derived instead of the base class

Tags: c++

I'm creating a 'basket' (container) to store 'items' (classes) that is derived from another class.
The idea is that the method `select` returns the right class (derived), not the base.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>

class Item;
class Pencil;

class Basket
{
public:
    Basket();
    void insert(int id, Item item);
    Item select(int id);
private:
    std::map<int, Item> basket;
};

class Item
{
};

class Pencil : public Item
{
public:
    Pencil() {}
    void draw() { std::cout << "stackoverflow" << std::endl; }
};

Basket::Basket() {}

void Basket::insert(int id, Item item)
{
    basket.insert(std::pair<int, Item>(id, item));
}

Item Basket::select(int id)
{
    return basket[id];
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Basket basket;
    Pencil pencil;
    basket.insert(1, pencil);
    auto redpen = basket.select(1);
    std::cout << typeid(redpen).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live preview](http://ideone.com/rR83L8)

> Output: 4Item (expecting to be 6Pencil)

This way I can't use the method `draw` because this isn't the item (class) that I added on the basket (container), it's converted to the base class.

Is there a way to return the right class, I mean, the derived one, but keeping that structure?

Thank you.

Comment: you can change the structure. e.g. you can deal with `shared_ptr<Item>`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - Do you have an example of using `shared_ptr` in that case? Thanks.

Comment: okay. due to the silly restrictions of SO comments I had to post it as [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23185582/464581). "silly": the only way to ensure high or even passable quality of technical things is to support free an rational debate and exchange of views, and quenching such debate is the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you requested in comments to the question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo>

class Item;
class Pencil;

class Basket
{
public:
    Basket();
    void insert( int id, std::shared_ptr<Item> item );
    auto select( int id ) -> std::shared_ptr<Item>;
private:
    std::map< int, std::shared_ptr<Item> > basket;
};

class Item
{
public:
    virtual ~Item() {}
};

class Pencil
    : public Item
{
public:
    Pencil() {}
    void draw() { std::cout << "stackoverflow" << std::endl; }
};

Basket::Basket() {}

void Basket::insert( int const id, std::shared_ptr<Item> const item )
{ basket[id] = item; }

auto Basket::select( int const id )
    -> std::shared_ptr<Item>
{ return basket[id]; }

int main()
{
    Basket basket;
    basket.insert(1, std::make_shared<Pencil>() );
    auto redpen = basket.select( 1 );
    std::cout << typeid(*redpen).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The unique problem that I can see is that you need to use std::make_shared and it leaves the API a little complicated to handle, is there another way? I mean, just using the `insert` and `select` methods, but handling at the same time with the problem (inside of the classes)?

Comment: there are lots of variants. e.g. pass a `Pencil` object and copy it. or pass the arguments needed to create it, to a templatized `insert` methods. or pass a `Pencil` object factory. or pass a type identifier. or pass a raw pointer. etc. i think most of these are more complicated and less safe. but ymmv.

Comment: Look the way that I tried: [live preview](http://ideone.com/oPJ8Fe) - It doesn't work. I saw somewhere that I can also use typecasting, but I'm lost with this.

Comment: oh well, the *technical* problem in [that code](http://ideone.com/oPJ8Fe) is just that `Item` needs to be a polymorphic class, i.e. have at least one `virtual` member function, which by convention is the destructor. but at the *design* level it's pretty unsafe to deal only with raw pointers. even you pass in a raw pointer, put in a smart pointer such as `std::shared_ptr` immediately, and return that, to take properly care of ownership.

Comment: Really, what is happening with me, I changed and I put the destructor as virtual and the error continues (without std::shared_ptr yet, just to test the technical first). - [live preview](http://ideone.com/oPJ8Fe) - (and sorry my lack of understanding)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the next problem, now manifesting. To call a member function it must be known statically, at compile time. And `Item`, the statically known object type, has no `draw` member. The most clean solution is to add a virtual `draw` member function in `Item`. An unclean solution is to use `dynamic_cast` to downcast the pointer, and call the method on the downcasted pointer.

Comment: Now it's working and I followed the 'clean' way that you said. Just before I accept your answer, answer me just another thing: Seeing [this (live preview)](http://ideone.com/oPJ8Fe) - What you would change in order to leave it safe? It's really needed to add the `std::shared_ptr`? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I would do this thing at all :-) But you need to automate ownership (final `delete`) in some way. All experience says that manual ownership management introduces complexity, so it steals programmer's time, and results in bugs. I would just use `shared_ptr` for the ownership here, because the design, using a polymorphic collection, is basically one that fits the idea of shared objects.

Comment: The unique 'problem' that I see is what I told you, the api, the user needs to use the `std::make_shared` in order to use the methods and it's not nice, what you would do in order to reverse that 'problem'?

Comment: well it depends. if the `insert` is often used in combination with object creation, then let it do the object creation. this means making it a template, or have one such function for each possible type (the latter restricts the set of possible types). then if also need to support objects coming from elsewhere, add an insert function for that (like the one you have now). it's not more either/or than one decides. just provide convenience syntactic sugar for what appears to be too verbose.

Comment: I just realized that isn't possible to use the draw method, am I wrong? I got errors: `error: 'class Item' has no member named 'draw'`.

Comment: @SH.0x90: you're right, but this is the reason why I added a virtual destructor to `Item`, and the reason for dealing with pointers to objects instead of object values. The virtual destructor makes `Item` a **polymorhic class**, which means that you can use `dynamic_cast` on a raw pointer, or `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` on a `std::shared_ptr`. E.g. after a successful cast to pointer to `Pencil` you can call the `Pencil` class' `draw` method. An alternative is declare the `draw` method as virtual up in the `Item` class. If you can practically do that, that's probably best.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a derived class by value, because then you get slicing, which just means copying of the derived as if it was only a base, leaving everything added behind (including any hint it should have been a derived).

Instead, return a pointer to a newly-allocated derived as a base*. Don't forget cleaning that up though.
In order to catch failure to delete, you might look into smart-pointers, also for sharing cached return values.
When the returned value is actually present for as long as needed anyway, you could also return a `const& base`.

Answer (score 1):

You would like to use C++ polymorphism with RTTI (Run-time Type Identification). One solution is to use pointer, thus to have:

```
class Basket
{
public:
    Basket();
    void insert(int id, Item *item);
    Item *select(int id);
private:
    std::map<int, Item*> basket;
};
```

This will need some dynamic allocations (new operations), and you can get rid of delete operation by using std::shared_ptr of memory header, with C++11.